# How to remove an agent from a set of agents in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a group of hospitals that must treat the wounded, but the care depends on how close they are to the wounded, that is, the closest hospital must care for them, but if it is full, the next closest hospital must care for them, and so on. .
For this, I created two sets of agents (injured and hospitals) and I gave the hospitals a property called nearby hospitals (which is a set of hospitals) so that the injured person eliminates from that set the hospitals that are close and are full.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! As far as I understood, you can use the `with` command, for example like this: `let free-hospitals hospitals with [patients-number < patients-max]`. This will give an agentset of all hospitals with free capacities, when `patients-number` and `patients-max` are hospitals-own variables.
If this does not help, it would be great it you could add a minimal reproducable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question.

Comment: Also, there is no actual question in this post. What is your question exactly, and what is going wrong in what you tried? Is there a reason why you want to add/withdraw agents to/from agentsets instead of using a combination of `min-one-of`, `distance` and `with`?